# Google bar chart: getting -1 for underscore data values

Tags: google-visualization

why do I get the "-1" string displayed below, even though I submit an underscore "_" to indicate missing data value here?

[My bar chart - please click to see the URL parameters](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=700x280&cht=bvo&chco=3399FF,CCCCFF&chd=t:_,_,_,-2064|3927,6133,8053,2802&chxl=0:|2010-44|2010-45|2010-46|2010-47&chxt=x,y&chxs=0,006633,12,0,_,000000&chxr=1,-2064,8053&chds=-2064,8053&chbh=140,10,0&chm=N,,0,,12|N,,1,,12)

[image]

Is this a bug in Google Charts?

I suspect they use -1 internally to indicate NULL values, but because I use **&chds=-2064,8053** it becomes visible. They should use a MIN-1 value instead...

Thank you!
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround is to use a value lower than the min value in range, i.e. **-2065** here or you can also use **-1e9** to have a shorter string.

Here is [the URL](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=700x280&cht=bvo&chco=3399FF,CCCCFF&chd=t%3a-1e9,-1e9,-1e9,-2064|3927,6133,8053,2802&chxl=0%3a|2010-44|2010-45|2010-46|2010-47&chxt=x,y&chxs=0,006633,12,0,_,000000&chxr=1,-2064,8053&chds=-2064,8053&chbh=140,10,0&chm=N,,0,,12|N,,1,,12) for the image below:

[image]